# Eclipse fails to deploy all dependencies to Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am running into a ClassNotFoundException while running a webapp in Tomcat6 from Eclipse. My webapp (projectA) has two project dependencies - one is a standard project (projectB) and the second is another web project (projectC).

I have setup Tomcat as a Server in the Servers tab and both projectA and projectC are deployed to Tomcat. I can run and debug projectC with no problems. I can run/debug projectA, but none of the classes from projectC can be found.

I've taken a look at tomcat/webapps/projectA/WEB-INF/lib directory and the jar for projectC is not there. The classes for projectC are also missing from tomcat/webapps/projectA/WEB-INF/classes, however all the classes from projectB are there.

When I look at the buildpath->projects list for projectA, both projectB and projectC are listed. When I look at the buildpath->Order and Export list for projectA, both projectB and projectC are listed.

I'm assuming that the issue revolves around the fact that projectC is a web project and not a standard project - but I'm not sure what the workaround is.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be the deployment assembly. Open the properties for project A and go to deployment assembly (on the left). If project C isn't listed there, click add and select project C (and any other dependencies project A has).

Comment: I have projectC as a source and the deploy path is "WEB-INF/lib". It appears though that all this is doing is adding the jars that are dependencies of projectC to the projectA deployment - not adding projectC to the deployment.